# InvalidationListener vs. ChangeListener

Tags: java, javafx, listener

I have the use case, where I want to bind multiple `ObservableValue`s onto one `Observable`, as I am actually not interested, what the value change is, I only need a means to get notified when it changes.

So this is the Observable binding, I came up:

```
BooleanBinding() {
    {
        super.bind(proxy.activeShipProperty());
        INavigableVessel activeShip = proxy.getActiveShip();
        super.bind(activeShip.getLoadBinding());
        if (activeShip instanceof IShip) {
            super.bind(((IShip) activeShip).travelState());
        } else {
            super.bind(((IConvoy) activeShip).getOrlegShip().travelState());
        }
        super.bind(date.dayDateBinding());
    }
    private boolean value = true;
    @Override
    protected boolean computeValue() {
        value = !value;
        return value;
    }
};
```

And then this test code, to verify it works as expected:

```
Observable observable = contentProvider.createObservable(ENoticeBoardType.SHIP_WARE_INFO, proxy);
IntegerProperty invalidationCounter = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);

InvalidationListener listener = observable1 -> invalidationCounter.setValue(invalidationCounter.get() + 1);
observable.addListener(listener);

// When
dayBinding.invalidate();
loadBinding.invalidate();
travelState.set(EShipTravelState.ANCHOR);
activeVessel.set(mock(IShip.class));

// Then
assertEquals(4, invalidationCounter.get());
```

Turns out it does not. The invalidationCounter is only increased once on the first invalidate call.

However when I handle the BooleanBinding from above as `ObservableValue`, I can add a ChangeListener:

```
ChangeListener listener = (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> invalidationCounter.setValue(invalidationCounter.get() + 1);
observable.addListener(listener);

// When
dayBinding.invalidate();
loadBinding.invalidate();
travelState.set(EShipTravelState.ANCHOR);
activeVessel.set(mock(IShip.class));

// Then
assertEquals(4, invalidationCounter.get());
```

This works as expected.

What I would like to know/have confirmed: The InvalidationListener is only called once, when the `Observable` becomes invalid, it then does not change back to valid, so that it could become valid again. With a `ChangeListener` however the new value is forced to be computed, hence the `ObservableValue` becomes valid again.

Based on this observation, is there any use case where I actually can use an [`Observable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/Observable.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Observable` is just an interface and the implementation determines, if calling `invalidate` triggers the listeners in a certain state. The behaviour you observe here is `BooleanBinding` triggering just a single `invalidation` update until the value is retrieved using the `get()` method.
The observers are expected to know that the value may have changed once the listeners have been notified.

This is an optimisation to avoid unnecessary computations. E.g. consider the following scenario: there are three `BooleanProperty`s `b1`, `b2` and `b3` and you're interested in `b1 && (b2 || b3)`. In this case you can apply short circuit evaluation which does not require you to evaluate `(b2 || b3)`, if `b1` is `false` and evaluating `(b2 || b3)` does not require you to evaluate `b3`, if `b2` is `true`. If `b2` and/or `b3` are expensive to compute, it makes the code more performant to not evaluate them, if you can avoid it, e.g. use the following implementation

```
BooleanBinding binding = new BooleanBinding() {
    {
        bind(b1, b2, b3);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean computeValue() {
        if (!b1.get()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (b2.get()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return b3.get();
        }

        // the above is basically a longer version of

        // return b1.get() && (b2.get() || b3.get());

        // to highlight the short circuiting behaviour
    }
};
```

`ChangeListener`s in contrast to `InvalidationListener`s require the new value to be passed to them so adding any `ChangeListener` results in `get()` being called and every `invalidation` call triggers a call of `computeValue`.